# Tkinter root_window.destroy() error

Tags: python, tkinter

Quite simplyfied version of my app :D(In my app I can see the Tkinter window, because for some time it is doing other stuff):

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
         self.okno=Tk()
         #other stuff ->sufficient time to show the Tk() window
         self.okno.destroy()
a=App()
mainloop()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    mainloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 361, in mainloop
    _default_root.tk.mainloop(n)
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

The reason for this is that I want to show them my beautiful app instead of Toplevel() without me-defined "parent" with an ugly grey window. But first I have to check if they registred for my app.

Comment: This logic doesn't make much sense to me... Why call `destroy` _before_ calling `mainloop`? Even if "sufficient time" passes, the window shouldn't appear until mainloop is called.

Comment: you are mainlooping, what? you need to make it clear to interpreter.

Comment: @Lafexlos just solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again I can't answer my own question, because I don't have sufficient reputation. So I'm answering via my another account which I BTW cannot use for posting questions :D.

Boy if u need to call destroy() while instantiating your App class and before mainloop() so much, you can add a condition for mainloop(). For example:

```
class App:
def __init__(self):
     self.okno=Tk()
     #other stuff ->sufficient time to show the Tk() window
     self.sorry_just_closed=True
     self.okno.destroy()
a=App()
if a.sorry_just_closed!=True:
    mainloop()
```